# Group multiple attributes based on category JAVASCRIPT. Works for one but not all attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JSON string and I am trying to group this up by category.

For example:

```
[{
    "category": "Messaging",
    "data": [7433],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Price Promo",
    "data": [774],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Usability",
    "data": [5993],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Messaging",
    "data": [7624],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Price Promo",
    "data": [900],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Usability",
    "data": [5865],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Messaging",
    "data": [7161],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Price Promo",
    "data": [1005],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}, {
    "category": "Usability",
    "data": [5940],
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2
}]
```

To (expected outcome):

```
{
    label: 'Messaging',
    data: [7433, 7624, 7161],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 2
  }
```

There are three categories in total. How do I do this in javascript:

Attempted code below but this only works for data attribute and not backgroundColor and borderColor etc:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stackBarData.length; i++) {
  var categoryName = stackBarData[i].category;
  if (!groups[categoryName]) {
    groups[categoryName] = [];
  }
  groups[categoryName].push(stackBarData[i].data);
}

stackBarData = [];
for (var categoryName in groups) {
  stackBarData.push({
    label: categoryName,
    data: groups[categoryName]
  });
}

dataSet = stackBarData.map(x => ({
  label: x.label,
  data: x.data.map(y => y[0])
}));
```

How do i change the above to include backgroundColor, borderColor, borderWidth in my groupings?

Comment: Why is `borderWidth` a single number in the result? What if the input objects don't have the same borderWidth?

Comment: It always has the same borderWidth

Comment: And `data` is always an array with a single element?

Comment: Yup data always has one value but when i group it together it should be [X,Y,Z]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by category and take out the values for adding to an array.

```js
var json = '[{"category":"Messaging","data":[7433],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255,99,132,1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Price Promo","data":[774],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Usability","data":[5993],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Messaging","data":[7624],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255,99,132,1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Price Promo","data":[900],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Usability","data":[5865],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Messaging","data":[7161],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255,99,132,1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Price Promo","data":[1005],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)","borderWidth":2},{"category":"Usability","data":[5940],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)","borderWidth":2}]',
    result = Object.values(JSON
        .parse(json)
        .reduce((r, { category, borderWidth, ...o }) => {
            r[o.category] = r[o.category] || { category, data: [], backgroundColor: [], borderColor: [], borderWidth };
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[o.category][k] = (r[o.category][k] || []).concat(v));
            return r;
        }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the full objects that you want in your first loop, and push each property onto the corresponding arrays.

```js
var groups = {};
stackBarData.forEach(d => {
  var categoryName = d.category;
  if (!groups[d.category]) {
    groups[d.category] = {
      label: d.category,
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: [],
      borderColor: [],
      borderWidth: d.borderWidth
    };
  }
  groups[d.category].data.push(d.data[0]);
  groups[d.category].backgroundColor.push(d.backgroundColor);
  groups[d.category].borderColor.push(d.borderColor);
});

stackBarData = Object.values(groups);
```

Comment: Getting an error ',' js expected next to stackBarData

Comment: Sorry, left out the `)`.